# Using more threads brings small performance gains, using more apps brings large

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, caching

My application is a brute-force optimizer. In order to improve its performance, I decided to use multithreading. The task is easily paralellizable - split the search space, use a thread for each chunk and then merge the results.

On my CPU with 12 virtual cores, the speedup using multiple threads topped at cca 230% at 5 threads. I do not have a profiler capable of showing cache misses and as the application searches through objects that do not fit into cache, I figured that cache is the bottleneck.

Then I launched the application in multiple instances, each with 5 threads. The average runtime of each instance was nearly the same as the runtime of one separate instance run on its own. Hence, I get a 3-fold increase in speed with no code, and the cache does not seem to be the problem.

My questions are the following:

1. What could be hindering the speedup stemming from using more threads, knowing that cache/memory bandwidth is not the cause and neither is available computing power?
2. What tools can I use to find the cause myself (assuming e.g. there can be more causes to this issue)?

The code snippet used to paralellize the task onto more threads is

```
 List<QSettings> xSplittedSettings = mxSettings.split(xThreadCount);
 List<Task<QResults>> xTasks = new QList<Task<QResults>>();

 for (int xThreadIdx = 0; xThreadIdx < xThreadCount; xThreadIdx++)
 {
     int xThreadIdx_ = xThreadIdx;
     xTasks.add(Task.Factory.StartNew<QResults>(() => performMainCycle(mxCandidate.clone(), xSplittedSettings[xThreadIdx_])));
 }

 Task.WaitAll(xTasks.toArray());
```

I have checked that when runing with multiple threads, each thread is calculating only the corresponding part of the problem. I also checked that all threads calculate simultaneously. However, when there is one instance with 5 threads, the Task Manager shows barely more than 15% of the CPU being used.

Any hint is much appreciated, 
Daniel

Comment: Multi-threading issues are hard and complex to diagnostics. It would require a deeper exam of your hole application, not just this peace of code.

Comment: be careful with `Task.Factory.StartNew` without specifing a `TaskSchedueller` it will use `TaskSchedueller.Current` if you don't pass one in and you could potentially queue stuff to be done on the UI thread instead of the thread pool, always pass in `TaskSchedueller.Default` to make sure it goes to the thread pool or just use `Task.Run`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Thanks for pointing that out. I tried fiddling around with the TaskCreationOptions and the TaskScheduler.Default and basically everything is the same (there was some noticeable improvement with TaskCreationOptions.None, but 10 threads still consume ~ 30% of CPU).